# How to declare a class as extending a function with implicit parameters

Tags: function, scala, implicit

I would like to define a function that takes one explicit and one implicit parameter, like so:

```
def foo(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) : Int
```

but as a class or object, like so

```
object Foo extends ((Int,Int) => Int) {
  def apply(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) : Int = { ... }
}
```

so that the function can be called like this:

```
implicit val b = 2
val g = Foo(1)
```

I fail to get the declaration of the base from which class `Foo` should extend right.
How can this be done?

Comment: why, in this example, do you need, "extends ((Int,Int) => Int)"? Compiles fine without.

Comment: so that I can pass a Foo where an (Int,Int) => Int is expected

Comment: right, that's why I said, "in this example"

Comment: @virtualeyes uh, ok. :-) You know how it is with examples.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. *Function2[T1, T2, R]* declares the abstract method *apply(t1: T1, t2: T2): R*, so if you want to mix in *Function2*, you have to implement this arity-2 *apply* method, which has a different signature than the curried version you would like to use.

Answer (score 0):

So there are two parts to this question - firstly, how does one create an object that implements a function with a curried parameter list. And then, how does one make one of those parameter lists implicit.

The first of those is definitely possible. Note that a curried function is a function that returns a function. So `f(x: Int)(y: Int)` is actually a `Function1`, not a `Function2`:

```
scala> def f(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
f: (x: Int)(y: Int)Int

scala> f _
res0: Int => Int => Int = <function1>
```

And you can certainly create a class that implements this:

```
scala> object Foo extends (Int => Int => Int) {
     |   def apply(x: Int) = {(y: Int) => x + y}
     | }
defined module Foo

scala> Foo(1)(2)
res1: Int = 3
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any way to make the second parameter list implicit.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than extending `(Int, Int) => Int` you could use an implicit conversion:

```
class Foo(f: (Int, Int) => Int) {
  def apply(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) : Int = f(a, b)
}

implicit def Foo_to_Function2(foo: Foo) = (x: Int, y: Int) => foo(x)(y)
```

Test:

```
val foo = new Foo(_ * 10 + _)
foo(4) //error since no implicit Int yet
{
  implicit val impint = 5
  foo(4)  //45
}  
def takesF2(f: (Int, Int) => Int) = f(1, 2)
takesF2(foo)  //12 - works as normal Function2
```

Comment: BTW I tried just extending `(Int, Int) => Int`, but the problem is that `def apply(a: A, b: B): C` and `def apply(a: A)(implicit b: B): C` end up as the same thing in bytecode terms, so it's illegal to have both.

Answer (score 0):

A question is: 
Why do you need necessarily to pass that object Foo to "where an (Int,Int) => Int is expected" ?

I suppose that object Foo shall have some more special features which does exhance it beyond being a function?

It seems better to separate two concerns here: 
a) The function (Int)(implicit Int) => Int
and 
b) the object Foo

```
object Foo {
  def apply(a: Int, b: Int) : Int = { ... }
}

def foo(a: Int)(implicit b: Int) : Int = Foo(a, b)

implicit val m:Int = 42

foo(5)  // --> res1: Int = 47
```

You may consider 'foo' a "companion function" if you like ...

Beside that: I suppose trying to apply an (Int)(implicit Int)=>Int "where an (Int,Int) => Int is expected" may not work, as these types are not identical. At least when you try to put that into a

```
def bar(f:(Int,Int)=>Int) = ....
```

The method bar would call its parameter f with two arguments anyway, as it expects it to take two, and cannot assume that the provided function in f is indeed able to work with implicits.